# printing preview IE

Tags: javascript, html, .net, css, asp-classic

Chromes new printing preview page where you see how the print will look before your printing it out, Is that possible to achieve the same preview in IE or which side jumps need to be done

I have the option to open the html with the print css in a new page,(but its not that pretty) but i was wondering if there where other options for getting that same chrome look?

Print view atm see the image below: chrome

[image]

Print view atm see the image below: IE

[image]

I prefer to use html, css & javascript but im open to .net solutions

Comment: So essentially you want to present the user with a view of how the page will print in a modal dialogue?

Comment: I guess you could achieve this using an iframe element and your print CSS.